# How much power design for pulsed-type VCSEL?

Tags: power, converter

I am designing a VCSEL board. VCSEL is 100 W optical power, typical operating voltage is 20 V, and operating current is 25 A.

I think that the power calculation is 20 * 25 = 500 W. But it is pulsed type; pulse length is 16 ns, and disable time is 5000 ns, so I think the average power is 500 W * 16 / 5000 = 1.6 W, and current will be 1.6 W / 20 V = 0.08 A.

But I'm worried about peak current; 0.08 A and 25 A are so different.

How much output current converter will be needed for about 20 V, 25 A, and 0.3% duty cycle? For example 20 V / 1 A or 20 V / 25 A.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 20V power supply need only supply the average power - 0.003*500 = 1.5W.

The 25A will most likely be supplied by a very low ESR/ESL capacitor very close to the switch (typically a MOSFET) and the laser diode. It only has to supply the current for 16ns so the capacitance required will only be the order of 1uF. The inductance and resistance in that loop has to be very small. The supply then has 5usec to leisurely recharge the cap to full voltage. Higher voltages reduce the effect of the inductance allowing faster rise times.

Eg.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Z6hq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You may well need other circuits operating from the 20V supply such as the switch- and the driver for the switch - this is just the contribution of the drive for the VCSEL diode itself.

Comment: Really thanks for comment! It is very useful to me! Have a nice day!!!

Comment: Have a nice coffee!!